# nativescript sidedrawer doesn't work

Tags: nativescript

I've been trying to implement sidedrawer for a week now, I followed everything in the documentation, when i slide the screen it throws this unfriendly exception. but the problem might be ViewChild because this.sidedrawer is undefined. ([the problem issued in the GitHub and there is a solution but neither of them works](https://github.com/telerik/nativescript-ui-feedback/issues/430)) 
i'm using angular, so this is the component i have:

```
<ActionBar class="action-bar">
  <Label class="action-bar-title" text="Restaurant List Nearby"></Label>
  <button text="List Mode" (tap)="enableListMode()"></button>
</ActionBar>


<RadSideDrawer tkExampleTitle tkToggleNavButton >
  <StackLayout tkDrawerContent class="sideStackLayout" >
    <StackLayout class="sideTitleStackLayout">
        <Label text="Navigation Menu"></Label>
    </StackLayout>
    <StackLayout class="sideStackLayout">
        <Label text="Primary" class="sideLabel sideLightGrayLabel"></Label>
        <Label text="Social" class="sideLabel"></Label>
        <Label text="Promotions" class="sideLabel"></Label>
        <Label text="Labels" class="sideLabel sideLightGrayLabel"></Label>
        <Label text="Important" class="sideLabel"></Label>
        <Label text="Starred" class="sideLabel"></Label>
        <Label text="Sent Mail" class="sideLabel"></Label>
        <Label text="Drafts" class="sideLabel"></Label>
    </StackLayout>
    <Label text="Close Drawer" color="lightgray" padding="10" style="horizontal-align: center" (tap)="onCloseDrawerTap()"></Label>
</StackLayout>
<StackLayout tkMainContent class="page">
    <MapView></MapView>
  </StackLayout>
</RadSideDrawer>
```

and the code:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ChangeDetectorRef,ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import {registerElement} from "nativescript-angular/element-registry";
import { Router } from "@angular/router";
registerElement("MapView", () => require("nativescript-google-maps-sdk").MapView);
import { RadSideDrawerComponent, SideDrawerType } from "nativescript-ui-sidedrawer/angular";
import { RadSideDrawer } from 'nativescript-ui-sidedrawer';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-map-mode',
  moduleId: module.id,
  templateUrl: './map-mode.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./map-mode.component.css']
})
export class MapModeComponent implements OnInit {


  private _mainContentText: string;

  constructor(private _changeDetectionRef: ChangeDetectorRef,
    private router: Router) { }

  @ViewChild(RadSideDrawerComponent) public drawerComponent: RadSideDrawerComponent;
  private drawer: RadSideDrawer;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
      //fairly certain this statement is never entered
      this.drawer = this.drawerComponent.sideDrawer;
      this._changeDetectionRef.detectChanges();
  }

  ngOnInit() {

   }

   public openDrawer() {
       console.log("Drawer method reached"); 
       console.log(this.drawer); //returns undefined
       this.drawer.showDrawer();
   }

   public onCloseDrawerTap() {
       this.drawer.closeDrawer();
   }
  enableListMode()
  {
    this.router.navigate(["resList"])

  }
}
```

the exception:

> JS: Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode()
>   to enable the production mode. System.err:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.FrameLayout.setVisibility(int)' on a null object
>   reference System.err:     at
>   com.telerik.android.primitives.widget.sidedrawer.RadSideDrawer.handleOnDown(RadSideDrawer.java:452)
>   System.err:     at
>   com.telerik.android.primitives.widget.sidedrawer.RadSideDrawer.onGesture(RadSideDrawer.java:430)
>   System.err:     at
>   com.telerik.android.primitives.widget.sidedrawer.RadSideDrawer.onInterceptTouchEvent(RadSideDrawer.java:420)
>   System.err:     at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2108)
>   System.err:     at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
>   System.err:     at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2197)
>   System.err:     at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
>   System.err:     at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2197)
>   System.err:     at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
>   System.err:     at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2197)
>   System.err:     at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
>   System.err:     at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2197)
>   System.err:     at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
>   System.err:     at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2197)
>   System.err:     at
>   com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2403)
>   System.err:     at
>   com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1737)
>   System.err:     at
>   android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2812)
>   System.err:     at
>   com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2364)
>   System.err:     at
>   android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:9520) System.err:
>   at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4242)
>   System.err:     at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4095)
>   System.err:     at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3641)
>   System.err:     at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3694)
>   System.err:     at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3660)
>   System.err:     at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3786)
>   System.err:     at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3668)
>   System.err:     at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3843)
>   System.err:     at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3641)
>   System.err:     at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3694)
>   System.err:     at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3660)
>   System.err:     at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3668)
>   System.err:     at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3641)
>   System.err:     at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5938)
>   System.err:     at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5912)
>   System.err:     at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5873)
>   System.err:     at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6041)
>   System.err:     at
>   android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
>   System.err:     at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native
>   Method) System.err:     at
>   android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:323) System.err:     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) System.err:     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5480) System.err: 
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) System.err:     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>   System.err:     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
>   ActivityManager: Process org.nativescript.rest (pid 1096) has died
>   ActivityManager: cleanUpApplicationRecord -- 1096